# Name of a series of Novels involving a Hero Flying a Harrier Jump Jet

Tags: story-identification

There was a series of books set in the future, in a war with various mutants. The hero was a merc pilot who flew a highly modified Harrier Jump jet. There were lots of sci-fi technology and mutants. I can't remember the name of the books. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you mean a Harry Turtledove book, the one where he features the USS Missouri.

Comment: I was thinking about the same series today. I can't remember the name or author, but i remember that the title of the first book had eagle in it with some adjective and another word like silver eagles and blank. If you have found out what it is please post it.

Comment: Reminiscent of one of David Drake's series...?

Comment: Sounds a bit like the Amtrak Wars by Patrick Tilley, what with the mutants and sci-fi...though I dont think the the pilot from the first book (and sequels) was a merc

Answer (score 5):

*Silver Wings and Leather Jackets (Eagleheart, No 1)*

[A review that mentions the mutants and the jet](http://mcsmith187.wordpress.com/2014/06/18/eagleheart-1-silver-wings-and-leather-jackets-by-c-t-westcott/):

> Bucko is a young seventeen year old living at the Twenty-nine Palms airbase in southern California. In this world a mad Russian sub commander launched an attack on the west coast. The resulting radiation gave birth to the RIHMs(Radioactive Induced Human Mutations). Bucko’s father dies when his plane is shot down over Pasadena.
>
> The orphaned Bucko sets off with his girlfriend Melodie Lane to find out his inheritance. He meets up with Black Pugh an old buddy of his father. Pugh has his fathers old TAV-8B Harrier. Bucko will get it if he graduates from the FAC academy in Quantico.

Answer (score 2):

*[Wingman](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1215980.Wingman)* (Wingman #1) by [Mack Maloney](https://mackmaloney.wordpress.com/).

[image: Book cover]

> Disarmed and leaderless, the United States is united no longer. Washington has been reduced to a smoking pile of radioactive rubble. Out of the blasted ruins of a once great land emerges a hero for the ages, Hawk Hunter, the brilliant ace fighter pilot. A fearless man of extraordinary abilities crossing a war-blackened landscape, a nightmarish breeding ground of slavery, carnage, violence, and death. A savage lone warrior on the bloody road to retribution, keeping alive the indomitable spirit of a forgotten dream called "America."